# AngularJS and Servlet integration

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, servlets

I'm trying to call a function that returns me a json object from a servlet through a link.

My HTML link, call fTest function:

```
<td><a href="" ng-controller="minaplantaCtrl" ng-click="fTest(x.id_camion_descarga)">ver</a></td>
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('minaplantaCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
$scope.fTest = function(idDescarga){
      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/BD_INTEGRADA/UnionMinaPlanta?idDescarga="+idDescarga)
      .success(function (response) {$scope.descargas = response.descargas;});
      $window.alert(JSON.stringify($scope.descargas));
     };
});
```

when I press for the first time the link appears "undefined" in the alert

but when I press a second time if I can see the json object that returns in the alert

What may be happening when I press first the link? please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your are alerting $scope.descargas outside of the success callback therefore it truly is not defined yet try modifying it like this.

```
app.controller('minaplantaCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
$scope.fTest = function(idDescarga){
      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/BD_INTEGRADA/UnionMinaPlanta?idDescarga="+idDescarga)
      .success(function (response) {
         $scope.descargas = response.descargas;
         $window.alert(JSON.stringify($scope.descargas));
      });
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every server side request using $http in Angular is an AJAX i.e. an asynchronous call to server, you are assuming that your alert method will be called after the success response execution complete. But this is wrong.

This is where the concept of promises comes in Angular.

```
app.controller('minaplantaCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.fTest = function(idDescarga) {
      console.log("1");

      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/BD_INTEGRADA/UnionMinaPlanta?idDescarga="+idDescarga)
      .success(function (response) {
            $scope.descargas = response.descargas;
            console.log("2");
      });

      console.log("3");
      $window.alert(JSON.stringify($scope.descargas));
     };
});
```

So when you execute this code with a delay at server side, you will see the order of console log as: **1**, **3** and **2**.

So, your success function is executed when the response received from the server. So for the first time, the value in `descargas` variable is null but get's stored using first server response and next time, value from previous call is being displayed.